# Use Binomial Theorem to find the remainder of $32^{{32}^{32}}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Use  Binomial Theorem to find the remainder when $32^{{32}^{32}}$ is divided by $7$.

$$32^{{32}^{32}}=2^{5.{2}^{{160}}}$$
$$5.(3-1)^{160}=5\left(C_{0}3^{160} -C_{1}3^{159} \cdots -C_{159}3 +C_{160}\right)$$

I want to prove it using Binomial Theorem. I don't know what mod thing is.

Comment: Is answer $4$..

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Yes

Comment: Are you required to prove it using the Binomial Theorem, or was that simply your guess on how to proceed?

Comment: @BillDubuque I want to prove it using binomial theorem

Comment: Are you allowed to make any use of congruences or modular arithmetic?

Comment: @BillDubuque No, even I don't what this thing is .

Comment: Ok, I added a straightforward proof that uses only the Binomial Theorem and simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $\ (a+bc)^{\large k}\,\overset{\rm BT}=\, a^{\large k} + bn\ $ for some integer $\,n,\,$ by BT =  Binomial Theorem, so

$\quad \color{#c00}{32^{32}}\! = (-1+3\cdot 11)^{32} \overset{\rm BT}=  \color{#c00}{1+3n}$

$\quad \color{#0a0}{32^{\large 3}}\! = (2^5)^3\! = (2^3)^5\! = (1+7)^5 \overset{\rm BT}= \color{#0a0}{1+7k}$

$32^{\large\color{#c00}{32^{\Large 32}}}\! = 32^{\large\color{#c00}{ 1+3n}} = 32(\color{#0a0}{32^{\large 3}})^{\large n} = 32(\color{#0a0}{1+7k})^{\large n} \overset{\rm BT}= (4\!+\!7\cdot 4)(1+7j) = 4+7(\cdots)$

Answer (score 3):

As $2^3=1+7$

$2^{100}=(3-1)^{100}=3a+1$ where $a$ is some fixed integer

$2^{5\cdot2^{100}}=2^{5(3a+1)}=(2^3)^{5a}\cdot2^5=(1+7)^{5a}\cdot2^5=(1+7b)32=4+7(4+32b)$

Comment: $a$ isn't _any_ integer. It is _some_ integer.

Comment: @Wojowu, Thanks for your observation.